# JFrog installation keeps failing on Windows 10

Tags: windows, artifactory

I have been setting up JFrog Artifactory (jfrog-artifactory-oss-7.21.3-windows.zip) on Windows 10 but when I execute "C:\jfrog\artifactory\app\bin\artifactory.bat", I am getting the below error message. Tried running the batch file as administrator but encountered the same issue.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\jfrog\artifactory\app\bin\bin\server\dist\bundle.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

**Output:**

```
prompt 13:57:11.77>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\java-1.8.0-openjdk

prompt 13:57:17.54>echo %JFROG_HOME%
C:\jfrog

prompt 13:57:22.71>java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)
```

**Additional Info:**

Tried with JDK-11 also to see if it helps, but it doesn't work either.

```
prompt 16:54:38.85>java -version
openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for raising this. A fix is coming in the upcoming patch.

[Edit 9th July]
Patch is now available at https://jfrog.com/download-jfrog-platform/

Comment: Any tentative timeline on when it will be available or temporary fix? Do we have any bug reported, where I can track the status?

Comment: It is released just now. You can download and give it a try. https://jfrog.com/download-jfrog-platform/

Comment: It is working fine as expected now. Can you please explain one last query, what version of JDK is needed for the latest version? JDK11 or JDK_1.8 ?

Comment: JDK11 is pre-bundled in the zip.